# How to split array to a format as given using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My data is

```
["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"]
```

How can split this to

```
[
    { lat: 9.968034, lng: 77.906814},
    { lat: 8.699679, lng: 77.478347},
    { lat: 8.797406, lng: 80.895095}
];
```

Please help me to have a solution...

I tried as

```js
var jArray = ["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"];
var temp = {};

for(var j=0; j<jArray.length;j++){
  var tr = {
    'lat' :jArray[j][1],
    'lng' :jArray[j][0]
  }
  temp.push(tr);
}

console.log(temp)
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried and why it's not working?

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 4):

**You can try this.**

With the help of `map()` and `split()` functions.

```js
let arr = ["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"]

let op = arr.map(e => {
   let temp = e.split(',');
   return { lat:temp[0], lng: temp[1] };
})
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split an destrucure the array.

```js
var data = ["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"],
    result = data.map(s => 
        (([lat, lng]) => ({ lat, lng }))
        (s.split(','))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built in JSON parse for strings, which I think is what you have:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse("my json string");
```

to use this with your example would be:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(myMessage);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.counters.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.counters[i];
    console.log(counter.counter_name);
}
```

Try it, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and ES2015 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

```js
let data = ["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"]

let newArray = data.map(loc => {
  const [lat, lng] = loc.split(',')
  return {
    lat,
    lng
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: You can { lat , lng }  i guess in return.

Comment: You are right. I had different variable names before.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"];
var arrayOfObjects = [];

for(var item = 0; item < arrayOfString.length; item++){
   var latlng = {};
   var splittedValues = arrayOfString[item].split(",");
   latlng["lat"] = splittedValues[0];
   latlng["long"] = splittedValues[1]
   arrayOfObjects.push(latlng);
}

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is correct but you should split string by `,` delimiter using `.split()` to getting parts of string.

```js
var jArray = ["9.968034,77.906814", "8.699679,77.478347", "8.797406,80.895095"];

var temp = [];
for (var j=0; j<jArray.length;j++){
  temp.push({
    'lat': jArray[j].split(',')[0],
    'lng': jArray[j].split(',')[1]
  });
}
console.log(temp);
```

Also you can use `foreach` instead

```
var temp = [];
jArray.forEach(function(item){
  temp.push({
    'lat' :item.split(',')[0],
    'lng' :item.split(',')[1]
  });
});
```